# How to check for existing docker image in terminal?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, unix, docker

I'm creating a new tag from an existing image. But sometimes the image is missing, and the command fails.
So I need to check if an docker image is existing at all before running the command:

```
$ docker tag source:anything target:something
```

But how do I check for existing docker image and how do I use an if-statement correctly in the terminal?

```
if [docker source:anything] docker tag source:anything target:something fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the correct way to do it

```
if [[ "$(docker images -q myimage:mytag 2> /dev/null)" == "" ]]; then

// do something

fi
```

you could also use

```
[ ! -z $(docker images -q myimage:mytag) ] || echo "does not exist"
```

Comment: Could I do it the other way round for the one liner: Check if existing, then execute another command? Maybe `&&` instead of `||`?

Comment: What does `-z` do?

Comment: @user3142695 it mean True if the length of string is zero